# Animate State change in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, animation, textfield, swiftui

I‘m currently playing around with SwiftUI. In SwiftUI it‘s possible, to animate a State change for example like so:

```swift
struct Foo: View {
    @State private var show = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if show {
                Text("Foo")
            }
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.show.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Text(show ? "Hide" : "Show")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But if I have for example a TextField:

```swift
struct Foo: View {
    @State private var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField($text, placeholder: Text("Foo")) {
                print("editing ended")
            }
            if !text.isEmpty {
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text("Done")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I‘m not able to find a way to animate this change, because the State property is changed by the TextField without a call to withAnimation().

Is it possible to get this change animated?

Comment: What sort of animation would this be outside of SwiftUI? In other words, what "change" do you think is being animated here, and how?

Comment: What do you mean by outside of SwiftUI? In my example I want to fade the Button in and out, but I need this animation feature for more complex animations, which involve colors etc. But all the animations, which I need, would function normally, if the withAnimation() function was called.

Comment: Fade in\out the button or TextField? In your example you are trying to animate text that is being changed while the user tapping and it doesn't look like what you want

Comment: In example #1 there are two things, which happen, when I press the Button. Firstly the "Foo" Text is shown or hidden and secondly the text of the button is toggled between "Hide" and "Show". Both "changes" happen with the default animation, which is simply a fade animation. 
In example #2 the "Done" Button is shown as long as the text is not empty, otherwise it‘s hidden. This happens without an animation.
But it‘s not important, which animations exactly happen in which example, the only thing of my interest is, that in example #2 there is no animation while in example #1 there are some.

Comment: But in the first example you have a `withAnimation` wrapping the state change. In the second example you don't. So it is unclear what you imagine is supposed to animate.

Comment: @matt that‘s my whole point. How should I wrap a state change in the example #2? The state is changed by the TextField and not by my code so I can‘t put a withAnimation around it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just add the animation modifier to wrap your button

```
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      TextField($text, placeholder: Text("Foo")) {
        print("editing ended")
      }
//      if !text.isEmpty {
        Button(action: {}) {
          Text("Done")
        }
        .background(text.isEmpty ? Color.red : Color.yellow )
         //.animation(.basic(duration: 1))
        .animation(Animation.default.speed(1))
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Okay. I tried it, but unfortunately it does only fade in the Button but removes it immediately. Bug maybe? I tried it also with some modifier changes, for example `.foregroundColor(text.isEmpty ? .red : .green)` on the Button instead of the if, but that also doesn't animate.

Comment: My code should only fade in/out the button. The animation of foregroundColor really doesn't work. Try the same with background. Don't forget to put the changes before the animation modifier

Comment: Yeah I know, but it doesn’t fade out. Only in

Comment: Hmm. Pretty strange in/out works for me with this code

Comment: Yes I tried it now in Playground there it worked, but not for colors. In the Simulator it only works for fade in. I don’t know...

Comment: I tried on simulator works both for in/out and background color(foregroundColor wasn't animated). Try to play with, may be you missed something. I've added full body to the answer

Comment: Now I made a clean app with exactly this setup. This works now. It just not works with my more complex setup.

Comment: It stops to work, as soon as I add `.textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)` to the TextField. How strange is that??? I will nonetheless accept your answer, because it is basically correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194649/discussion-between-denfav-and-josef-zoller).

Answer (score 8):

`TextField("Placeholder", text:$text.animation())`

Everything that uses the text will be animated when it is changed.

Comment: Worked even on Toggle!